# hadoop nullpinter Exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop programming and i am trying to code on map side join but getting null pointer exception.
Kindly help and let me know the cause of problem .

```
package mapreduce.mapSideJoin;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;



public class mapSideJoinUserMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text > {

    private  HashMap<String, String> cacheMap = new HashMap<String , String>();
    private BufferedReader br ;

    protected void setup (Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        Path[] pathArray = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
        try {
        for ( Path eachPath : pathArray){
            //System.out.pritn(eachPath.toString());
            if(eachPath.getName().toString().trim().equals("custData.txt"));
            LoadHashMap(eachPath,context);
        }


        }

        catch(IOException e){

            System.err.println("An IOException was caught!");

        }




    }

    private void LoadHashMap(Path filePath, Context context) throws IOException{


        String strReadLine="";
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath.toString()));
        while((strReadLine=br.readLine())!= null){

            String[] wordArray = strReadLine.split(",");
            cacheMap.put(wordArray[0].trim(),wordArray[1].trim());
        }
        br.close();
    }

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value , Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        String [] word = value.toString().split(",");
        String name =cacheMap.get(word[0]);
         context.write(new Text(name), new Text(word[1]));
        //context.write(new Text("jdewdeded"), new Text("dededededede"));



    }
}
```

this is my map code 
and data file are

```
0001,Zunil Kumar , Mumbai,India
0002,vikas mandal, Haryana, India
0003,Karan, JFK,France
0004,manish,banglore,India
0005,devesh,meerut,India

0001,crax,2,300
0002,munch,1,10
0003,lays,1,20
0004,ship,1,200
0005,barOne,3,400
0002,crax,2,300
0001,kurkure,3,101
0003,milk,1,20
0004,butter,2,30
0005,meat,1,1220
0002,color,1,230
0003,dailrymilk,1,20
```

I

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace

Comment: HI  Makubex  http://stackoverflow.com/users/3792209/makubex, Thanks but i am new to java and hadoop , i will update with stackTrace soon

Comment: Hi @Makubex , if i understand correctly i have error in f24 line in mapSideJoinUserMapper.java:24

`2016-06-04 18:09:49,619 INFO [IPC Server handler 7 on 57884] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1465043841547_0001_m_000000_3: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at mapreduce.mapSideJoin.mapSideJoinUserMapper.setup(mapSideJoinUserMapper.java:24)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)`

Comment: It seems like like my Distributedcache is empty.
`public int run (String[] args) throws Exception{
  
  Configuration conf = this.getConf();
  Job job = new Job(conf , "MAp SideJoin ");
  job.setJarByClass(mapSideJoinDriver.class);
  job.setMapperClass(mapSideJoinUserMapper.class);
  job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
  DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("/user/hadoop/dir6_mapSideJoin/custData.txt"),conf);
  //DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URL("/user/hadoop/dir6_m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to implement the same logic what u are trying and got the output.You can try with the below code.

```
public class StackOverflowMapsideJoin {
public static class StMapperr extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>
{
    Text outkey=new Text();
    Text outvalue= new Text();
    HashMap<String,String> hmap=new HashMap<String,String>();
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException
    {
        Path paths[] =DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
        for(Path p :paths)
        {
            if(p.getName().equals("person.dat"));
            {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(p.toString()));
            //0001,Zunil Kumar , Mumbai,India
            String line=br.readLine();
            while(line !=null)
            {
                String cols[]=line.split(",");
                String id=cols[0];
                String name=cols[1];
                hmap.put(id, name);
                line=br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
            }
        }
    }
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        ////0001,crax,2,300
        String mapcols[]=values.toString().split(",");
        String cid=mapcols[0];
        String type=mapcols[1];
        outkey.set(hmap.get(cid));
        outvalue.set(type);
        context.write(outkey, outvalue);
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job=new Job(conf,"cdecedc");

    job.setJarByClass(StackOverflowMapsideJoin.class);
    job.setMapperClass(StMapperr.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/person.dat"), job.getConfiguration());
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?1:0);


}
```

}

PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF IT HELPS!!!

Comment: Yes  ishan , yes your code helped me but i have few question `   Text outkey=new Text();    Text outvalue= new Text(); ` and i want to know what is the benifit in doing this .In my code i every time i create a object but your are using one time object creation and updating the value of outKey and outValue. Does context.write create a object every time it is executed

Comment: @Anaadih.pradeep: Please see Tip6  http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/12/7-tips-for-improving-mapreduce-performance/ you will understand. We have to reuse writables instead of creating object for each record.. we can set the writable using set method.

Comment: @RamPrasad G  thank you  for the link it helped a lot .